# Loop through unknown number of folders with progressive names

Tags: bash, for-loop, ubuntu, directory

I am trying to use the bash to loop through an unknown number of folders which end with a progressive number starting from 0. Each folder is named processor* where * stands for the progressive number (e.g. processor0, processor1, processor2, etc..). Inside each loop the script should execute these commands `find ./ -name 'U' | while read U ; do cp "$U" ./0 ; done`.

My for loop looks like this:

```
for i in processor*; do
    cd ./processor$i
    find ./ -name 'U' | while read U ; do cp "$U" ./0 ; done
    cd ..
done
```

but it currently does not work.

Comment: What "does not work" actually means?

Comment: This is the error message ```./Allrun: line 2: cd: ./processorprocessor0: No such file or directory```

Comment: Then do `cd "$i"`. It's already a `processor*`.

Comment: Note that using `cd` in a script tends to be dangerous, because if it fails for any reason the rest of the script will blithely continue operating... in the wrong place, with [potentially disastrous consequences](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378942/cant-initialize-osx-interrogation-folder). It's much safer to use explicit paths, e.g. replace `cd someDir; find ./ ...` with `find someDir/ ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the syntax `for i in processor*`, the results of expanding `processor*` will be iterated over, and the variable `i` will hold the result for a given iteration.

From the [GNU HTML manual for bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html):

> The syntax of the `for` command is:
> `for name [ [in [words …] ] ; ] do commands; done` 
> Expand `words` (see [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)), and execute commands once for each member in the resultant list, with `name` bound to the current member.

For example, if the current working directory contained the directories `processor0`, `processor1`, and `processor_something_else`, and the expansion of `processor*` was in that order, then `i` will have the following value for the separate iterations:

- `i` has the value `processor0` in the first iteration
- `i` has the value `processor1` in the second iteration
- `i` has the value `processor_something_else` in the second iteration

The expression `./processor$i` then would evaluate to the following in each iteration:

- `./processorprocessor0`
- `./processorprocessor1`
- `./processorprocessor_something_else`

This is because the value of `i` will be expanded as the `cd` command is generated.

What you really want is to use `cd ./"$i"`.